# Less output does not show output in terminal after quitting it

Tags: bash, zsh, less

Previously, if I ran `something | less`, and then press `q`, it used to return me to the prompt with the output of `less` still visible.

```
$ seq 1 100 | less
1
2
3
4
:q
$ <prompt here. I can still see the output of less>
```

But now, after I installed Zsh (with oh-my-zsh. It doesn't work in bash too), the terminal looks like this:

```
$ seq 1 100 | less
<less shows up, I press :q and it is cleared>
$ <prompt here. Output of less disappears.>
```

I searched for a `less` config file and found none. Is there any way I can get `less` to behave the previous way? Having the output visible is very handy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
seq 1 100 | less -X
```

see: man less

```
-X or --no-init
Disables  sending  the  termcap  initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. 
This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something  unnecessary, like clearing the screen.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I added it to `~/.lesskey` and it runs with all the `git` etc.

Answer (score 9):

As jhscheer mentioned everything is in the man page for `less`

Add this to your zsh profile `.zshrc` to make it play nice with git :)

`LESS="-XRF"; export LESS`

-- EDIT

Actually in your case it's probably better to run the following command to avoid modifying the global behaviour of `less`:

`git config --global core.pager 'less -XRF'`